# WIndows 8.1 Universal Get network usage for each app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1-universal

I made a program to get network usage for windows 10 and windows 10 mobile. I can see a built in data usage in windows 10.
[image: Image1]

I can get network usage with this code:

```
connectionProfiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
```

But How can I do something like windows 10. a direct link to get values? Is there any way? Is it possible to help me?
Thanks.